# How do I know which objects cause the performance slowing?

Tags: performance

Something like Task Manager on Windows but inside the Blender scene.
I want to optimize scenes that are super slow, but dont know where to start. I don`t even have high poly objects or too much subdivision.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://code.blender.org/2021/05/mesh-editing-optimization-initial-steps/) and [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/optimizations/performance.html) articles for more information about optimization.

Comment: thanks, will do